# Сгруппировать последовательно идущие цифры в списке

Tags: python, python-3.x, циклы

Дан список с индексами, необходимо сгруппировать элементы списка, идущие последовательно и вывести номера элементов начала и конца т.е.

```
indexes=[1,2,3,32,33,35,70]
k=0
i=0
def Popytka_nomer_5(indexes,k,i):    
    for i in range(len(indexes)-1):
        print("Группа",k,'\tНачало',i)
        if indexes[i+1]==indexes[i]+1:
            continue
        k+=1
        print("\t\tКонец",i)
Popytka_nomer_5(indexes,k,i)
```

Выводит это

```
Группа 0        Начало 0
Группа 0        Начало 1
Группа 0        Начало 2
                Конец 2
Группа 1        Начало 3
Группа 1        Начало 4
                Конец 4
Группа 2        Начало 5
                Конец 5
```

А нужно

```
Группа 0        Начало 0
                Конец 2
Группа 1        Начало 3
                Конец 5
Группа 2        Начало 6
                Конец 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализация с циклом по условию (для более удобного перемещения между стартом и концом отрезка):

```py
indexes = [1, 2, 3, 32, 33, 34, 35, 70]

def Popytka_nomer_5(indexes, group = 0, i = 0):
    while i < len(indexes):
        j = i
        while j < len(indexes) -1 \
        and indexes[j+1] == indexes[j] + 1:
            j += 1
        print("Группа {}\tНачало {}".format(group + 1, i))
        print("\t\tКонец {}".format(j))
        i = j + 1
        group += 1

Popytka_nomer_5(indexes)
```

Реализация с циклом по итератору:

```py
indexes = [1, 2, 3, 32, 33, 34, 35, 70]

def Popytka_nomer_5(indexes, group = 0, i = 0):
    g = -1
    for i in range(len(indexes)):
        if g == -1:
            print("Группа {}\tНачало {}".format(group, i))
            g = group

        if i < len(indexes)-1 and indexes[i+1] == indexes[i] + 1:
            continue
        group += 1
        g = -1
        print("\t\tКонец {}".format(i))

Popytka_nomer_5(indexes)
```

Результат:

```
Группа 1    Начало 0
            Конец 2
Группа 2    Начало 3
            Конец 6
Группа 3    Начало 7
            Конец 7
```

В любом случае идти нужно до последнего элемента, а не до предпоследнего. Просто последний сравнивать ни с чем не нужно. А так вы теряли элемент

Answer (score 0):

Как вариант:

```
indexes = [1, 2, 3, 32, 33, 35, 70]
k = 0
i = 0 

def popytka_nomer_5(indexes, k, i): 
    fl = True   
    for i in range(len(indexes)-1):
        if fl: print("Группа", k, '\tНачало', i, indexes[i])
        if indexes[i+1] == indexes[i]+1:
            fl = False
            continue
        fl = True   
        k += 1
        print("\t\tКонец ", i, indexes[i])
    if not fl:    
        print("\t\tКонец ", i+1, indexes[i+1])
    else:
        print("Группа", k, '\tНачало', i+1, indexes[i+1])
        print("\t\tКонец ", i+1, indexes[i+1])

popytka_nomer_5(indexes,k,i)

print(indexes)
print(' 0  1  2   3   4   5   6')
```